# How did "sapere" lose the middle consonant P in its indicative present table?

Tags: etymology

As with most other Romance languages, the verb *sapere* has a very irregular indicative present conjugation table. For example (only focused ones are listed)

```
Latin    Italian   French  Spanish
----------------------------------
sapio    so        sais    sé
sapis    sai       sais
sapit    sa        sait
sapimus                        
sapitis                  
sapiunt  sanno
```

Except for French which I can't verify (*sache*), the subjunctive present table is mostly regular, unlike indicative (Italian *sappia*, Spanish *sepa*). The consonant in the middle (P or B or V) is lost altogether in *io, tu, lui* and *loro* conjugations.

Can anyone tell explain how *sapere* lost the middle consonant in those indicative present conjugations?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding _sappiamo_, since if it were regular it should be *_sapiamo_.

Comment: “the subjunctive present table is also regular”: do you mean “irregular”?

Comment: @DaG Nope. I wouldn't consider the double P as "irregular". Speaking of Spanish, the subj. present *sepo* is regular to the extent that Spanish changes vowels depending on stress. Other than that, it isn't any irregular on its own.

Comment: Thanks. Why don't you consider the doubling of the consonant irregular? Your question your rules, in a sense, but in an Italian standard 2nd conjugation verb, such as *temere*, no doubling happens (*temiamo*).

Comment: My doubt about the sentence “the subjunctive present table is also regular” is due to that “also”, so I can't parse it well. And _sapere_ is irregular indeed in the subjunctive too: _temere_ > _tema_, so it should be _sapere_ > *_sapa_, rather than _sappia_.

Comment: @iBug: The present subjunctive in Spanish is *sepa* and not *sepo.

Comment: Man, you really do not want me to do work today, posting all these interesting questions. Answer incoming in a few hours

Comment: @DaG I made another edit so it better resembles what I mean now.

Comment: @Charo Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: `sappiamo` isn't irregular, because of regular gemination befor `/j/`. See e.g. `doppio` < Lat. `duplus`.

Comment: @Rethliopuks Indeed, although the behaviour of yods in Italian is a bit more chaotic than in other Romance languages (in particular the form *sapiamo* is in fact attested)

Comment: @Rethliopuks: But this is not a rule of modern Italian; regular verbs do not geminate the consonant of their root before the 4th person suffix. For instance, _capiamo_, _rubiamo_ and so on.

Comment: Also small note: the French *sache*  indeed forms regularly from the Latin subjunctive, although the sound changes obscure it a bit (it should be *sapeat* > [sapjat] > [sapʤa] > [saʧə] > [saʃ] = *sache*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of this answer comes from material in

> Alkire, Ti, and Rosen, Carol. *Romance languages: A historical introduction.* Cambridge University Press, 2010

However this answer is a bit more speculative that my previous answer with the same source, because I couldn't find a complete treatment of the evolution of *sapĕo* either in that book or anywhere else. So the following answer is essentially me applying the regular changes found in that book (in particular the existence "analogic group" {*sapere*, *fare*, *dare*, *stare*, *avere*}) to this special case and describing what happens. I'm not a linguist, neither by formation nor by trade, so a lot of the explanations I write might be rubbish. The reconstructed and attested forms however do come from the book, so they should be reliable.

---

The Italian verb [*sapere*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sapere2/) (as the French *savoir* and Spanish *saber*) comes from Latin [*sapĕre*](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.17:469.lewisandshort.853309), which is one of the few Latin verbs of the III conjugation that got pushed to the II (hence becoming **sapēre). Let us take a look at its reconstructed conjugation in Vulgar Latin and its attested Old Italian forms.

```
 Vulgar Latin          |    Old Italian
----------------------------------------------------------
*sapĕo      > *sapio   |  sàccio/sappo/sao
*sapes      > *sapei   |  sapi
*sapet      > *sape    |  sape
*sapēmus    > *sapemoi |  sapemo > sapiamo
(*sapēte)   > *sapete  |  sapete
*sapent     > *sapen   |  sàcciono
```

Note that in the plural first person, the original form (**sapētis*) got replaced by the imperative form in all Italian verbs. Similarly, the plural first person got replaced by the present subjunctive form (**sapeamus*) (possibly because of the imperative value of present subjunctive).

In the passage to Old Italian, the third person plural is replaced by an analogic form obtained from the first person singular, probably because the original third plural forms were perceived as apocopes (for whatever reason, Italian developed a strong link between the first singular and third plural forms in all its verbs). Moreover the first singular form regularly turned the yod in a gemination of the previous consonant (possibly accompanied by palatalization).

The form *sao*, the one that prevailed in the end, is more mysterious. The best guess I can give is that it was interpreted as part of a family of very common verbs ending with *-ao* at the singular first person: *vao* > *vo*, *fao* > *fo*, **dao* > *do*, **stao* > *sto* (where most of them got this form from a regular lenition). The same phenomenon should be responsible for the change **ajo*> *ho* (and not the attested *aggio*) and for the apocopes that happen at the other singular forms (again, the third plural form is probably dragged by analogy with the first singular). This seems also to be the interpretation in Rohlfs, G. *Grammatica storica dell'italiano e dei suoi dialetti* (pg.284, my translation)

> *The present of 'sapere'.* The current Tuscan inflection *sò*, *sai*, *sa*, *sappiamo* (early *sapemo*), *sapete*, *sanno* shows a clear connection with the conjugation of *hò*, *stò*, *dò*, *vò*, *fò*. The ancient step of *sò* can be seen in the *sao* of the «Carte capuane» (960 d.C.). Ancient forms are *saccio* 'I know' (Guido Cavalcanti, Forese) and *sape* 'he knows' (Purg. 18,56, *uom non sape*). The first form is perhaps modelled on *faccio* and *taccio*, but it propagated also by the influx of the Sicilian poetic school: cfr. Sicilian and Calabrian *sacciu*.

So we end up with the modern forms

```
sao > so
sai
sa
sappiamo
sapete
sanno
```

(In fact it is almost certain that the attested form *sao* is a residual that survived in Campania, and that most of Italy was already using *so* at a very early period).