# Why is that the future/conditional stem of «essere» is [sar-] instead of [esser-]

Tags: etymology, tenses, conditional-mood

The Italian future/conditional tense is formed like many other Romance languages, that is *infinitive* + *habeo*/*habebam* (except Italian uses L *habuit* for conditional). The F/C stem for most words are the infinitive form, and some words have some sound changes (*avere* → *avr-*, *volere* → *vorr-* etc.), but one basic word *essere* has a vastly different stem from the infinitive, *sar-*. This is also the same in French (*être* → *ser-*) but not Iberian (ES/PT *ser* → *ser-*).

Comment: A similar thing happens also in Catalan: the infinitive is "ésser", but future is "seré", etc. and conditional is "seria", etc.

Comment: @Charo I've always thought Catalan is an Iberian language (groups with ES/PT/Galician).

Comment: @iBug Catalan is (one of) the modern descendent of the "langue d'oc" or occitan, also known as Provençal, who was spread from Piedmont to modern Cataluña and is most famous for its medieval literature. I'm sure Catalan has picked up a few of Iberian features along the centuries, just due to its geographical location, but that's not its origin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Alkire, T., & Rosen, C. (2010). Romance languages: A historical introduction. published by Cambridge University Press, section 7.8.1 *The main Romance future*:

> The future stem of ‘be’ is a special case. Forms like Popular Latin *ESSER - AT, instead of syncopating, lose their initial syllable to give Italian *sarà* and French *sera* (Spanish *será* could be from *ESSER - AT, but more plausibly derives from *SEDER - AT, given the evidence for syncretism). This apheresis, somewhat unusual in the history of Romance, was probably fostered by the present forms of ‘be’ that begin with [s]. The [a] in the Italian stem has been ascribed to analogy with *farà* ‘will do’, *darà* ‘will give’, and *starà* ‘will stay’, which in turn retain their [a] on the model of the monosyllabic present indicatives *fa*, *dà*, *sta* with stressed [a]. The three languages differ in the proximity of the future stem to the infinitive. They are identical in Spanish (*ser* ~ *ser-*), while in Italian and French the future stem has strayed away from the infinitives *essere* and *être*. *Être*, from Old French *estre*, results from the syncope of Popular Latin essere followed by [t] epenthesis. It had its own future *estra* ‘will be’ competing
> in Old French with *sera* and with *iert*/*ert*.

To summarize: regular sound changes would have produced a syncopated form **esr- > ?**err- (cfr. with *vedr-* for the verb *vedere*), but analogy with the forms of the present seems to have pushed for the loss of the initial vowel instead. The weird choice of the root vowel in Italian (compared to French) seems to have been by analogic pressure with the verb family *fare*/*stare*/*dare* which had a strong influence on the evolution of the Italian verbal system (compare with the effect they had on the [present tense of *sapere*](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10041/how-did-sapere-acquire-its-highly-irregular-indicative-present-table)).

Martin Maiden, in his *Linguistic History of Italy* concurs with this assessment (section 8.8.5):

> it is likely that *sarò*, the future of *essere*, is modelled on these verbs [*fare*/*stare*/*dare*].

Rohlfs, in his *Grammatica Storica dell'Italiano e dei suoi dialetti* is a bit more enigmatic, but fundamentally in agreement (paragraph 587):

> Il fiorentino *sarò* è fatto su *darò*, *starò*, *farò*, dove per ovvi motivi *a* non è passato a *e*.
>
> The Florentine *sarò* is modeled on *darò*, *starò*, *farò*, where for obvious reasons *a* has not changed to *e*.